# Is it OK to seal the top side of a deck concrete footing?

Tags: concrete, deck, footings, sealant

This is a follow up for this question [Deck footing 2" above the ground -does that apply to a patio? What is the reason behind the 2" restriction?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/117711/deck-footing-2-above-the-ground-does-that-apply-to-a-patio-what-is-the-reason)
I decided to have my concrete footing under the patio and covered with gravel (and possibly bricks on top of it. These are 10" sonotubes on top of which I installed these:
[image]

The concrete footing and part of the pipe side of the support will be under the patio bricks. 
I would like to seal the top side of the concrete pier with some sealant ([epoxy spray](http://www.globalindustrial.ca/p/building-materials/paint/aerosol/rust-oleum-1600-system-epoxy-rebar?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=Cj0KEQjwkZfLBRCzg-69tJy84N8BEiQAffAwqgY508svPeinvyUL43XAjNL-5ceLPn17c2RMo3pDJ4saAgde8P8HAQ)?) . Is that a good idea? I will also try to complete cover the screws and the foot of the support in one more layer of epoxy to make sure they will have a long life

The other option that I have would be to use concrete sealant I still have one tube of this: 
[image]

Comment: Why would you like to seal it?  If it was wood direct on concrete I would get it but you have a barrier between the wood and concrete already.

Comment: I just don't know if I have to , that is why I am asking. Besides that the concrete will sit under patio and it will be constantly wet/humid. I don't know if that is fine or not. The adjustable support might not be OK to sit in humidity all the time. That is why I am split between covering the footing with gravel vs covering it with bricks. One is OK in summer but bad in winter and viceversa

Comment: Concrete doesn't care about moisture unless it's reinforced concrete.  The support you added looks to be well painted and should stand up to the elements for 20 years or so.

Comment: I hope so, I have fence supports (spikes) that I put in the ground, made the same way, coated with that epoxy thing

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo: Even reinforced concrete doesn't care about moisture as long as there isn't any rebar actually exposed.  (Concrete is extremely alkaline, which inhibits the corrosion of steel rebar).  Fiber-reinforced concrete won't care even if some of the reinforcement _is_ exposed at the surface.